# Head pointer in linked list magically assigned, should not work but does

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

UPDATE: Please see David Grayson's response if you are in a similar position to mine and want to revise your program.

---

So I've been learning linked lists in CS202 and I have created a program that works, but should not. The exact reason it should not work is that I never assign the pointer in the first node to the next node, yet the program compiles and runs perfectly.

(Or at least, this is how I understand it. Of course, I must be incorrect on some level.)

I know this isn't the prettiest code, but I didn't want to mess with it when, for some reason, it works already.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//STRUCTS

struct node
{
    int num;
    node *ptrNext;
};

//FUNCTIONS

node *addNode(node *currentNode, int i)
{
    node *previousNode = currentNode;

    currentNode = new node;
    currentNode -> num = i;
    currentNode -> ptrNext = nullptr;

    previousNode -> ptrNext = currentNode;

    return currentNode;

}

void printList(node *printingNode)
{
    while (printingNode -> ptrNext != nullptr)
    {
        printingNode = printingNode -> ptrNext;
        cout << printingNode -> num << ", ";
    }
}

//MAIN

int main()
{
    node *head = new node;
    node *current;

    head -> num = NULL;
    head -> ptrNext = nullptr;

    current = addNode(head, 23);
    current = addNode(current, 28);
    current = addNode(current, 45);
    current = addNode(current, 57);

    printList(head);

    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles without errors or warning, and the output looks like this:

```
23, 28, 45, 57,
```

My instructor and I are baffled by this. How can, when used in the printList function, the head -> ptrNext be linked?

Comment: The `addNode` method sets up the next pointer: `previousNode -> ptrNext = currentNode;`. Unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: Your confusion might arise from this line: `currentNode = new node;`  You chose to reuse a variable name instead of making a new one, which makes the code look incorrect at first glance.  I probably would have written `node * newNode = new node;`, and gotten rid `previousNose` altogether.

Comment: "I probably would have written node * newNode = new node;, and gotten rid previousNose altogether." This did the trick, it makes a lot more sense now. I'm still not sure about the answer, specifically, to my question, but now at least I have a program that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The addNode function handles this. When addNode is called, it sets the value of ptrNext to the new node that's created.

Comment: But, I never do currentNode -> ptrNext = anything besides nullptr. That is to say, when head is currentNode, the first time addNode is called, the node it points to is only assigned ptrNext = nullptr.

Comment: but you do `*previousNode = currentNode` and `previousNode -> ptrNext = currentNode`

Answer (score 0):

When I do

```
 previousNode -> ptrNext = currentNode;
```

the pointer previousNode has been set to the head node and changes the ptrNext in the head node to the just-created one.

GaiusOctavian has a technically correct answer, but I didn't understand it because pointers are complicated. Thanks, though, for helping make it clear!

---

My new program takes advantage of David Grayson's advise:

```
node *addNode(node *inputNode, int input)
{
    node *newNode = new node;
    newNode -> num = input;
    newNode -> ptrNext = nullptr;

    inputNode -> ptrNext = newNode;

    return newNode;
}
```

This simply takes a node, creates a new one, then links the input node to the new one and spits out the new one.